# Which of the following statements is false for $S=\{d(x,y): x, y \in X\}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d)$ be a path connected metric space with at least two elements, and let

$$S=\{d(x,y): x, y \in X\}$$

Which of the following statements is not necessarily true?

A) $S$ is infinite

B) $S$ contains a non zero rational number.

C) $S$ is connected

D) $S$ is a closed subset of $R$.

how to look for this?

Answer (score 4):

$S$ is the continuous image of the connected set $X\times X$ under the map $f\colon X\times X\to \mathbb R$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto d(x,y)$. So it is connected. Since $X$ has at least two points $a,b$, it must contain both $0=d(a,a)$ and $d(a,b)>0$. So it contains the entire interval $[0,d(a,b)]$ since it is connected. Thus A,B,C are all necessarily true. To show that D) can fail, let $X=(0,1)\subset \mathbb R$ with the usual metric. Then $S=[0,1)$ and is not closed.